# Почему [ы], [и] и [у] не редуцируются качественно?

Tags: фонетика

Гласные [а], [о] и так далее изменяют качество звучания — становятся [^], [ъ], но [у] остаётся [у], а [и] — [и], меняя лишь долготу и напряжённость. Почему?

Я бы предположил, что это из-за лабиализации, но лабиализированный [о] отлично редуцируется.

Comment: Сложный вопрос. А вы могли бы привести примеры слов?

Comment: Лишиться — [л'ишы́цъ], вырываться — [вырыва́цъ], скучающий — [скуч'•а́jуш'иj]; и это при том, что [а], [о] и так далее вполне себе становятся [ъ] и [^] — голова — [гъл^ва́], лесистый — [л'и(э)с'и́стыj], а [у], [ы] и [и] лишь теряют в долготе и, возможно, напряжённости. Почему?

Answer (score 2):

[image: Таблица]

https://zen.yandex.ru/media/id/5f500ab55e93ab5121b11ac1/riad-i-podem-o-klassifikacii-glasnyh-poeziia-5f570f3f3b3fcc0674f48c31

Фонемы [ы], [и] в безударной позиции  **не меняют качество** (при первой степени редукции), а реализуются как звук, похожий на [ы], [и], только менее длительный и напряженный.

Эти фонетические формы, как и форма [ʌ], наиболее **естественны и удобны**  для произношения. Поэтому они  замещают и фонемы [о] и [э], которые обычно не произносятся без ударения.

Почему же звук [у] **не использует** в безударной позиции  эти «универсальные» формы, а сохраняет свою собственную? Возможно, подобная  универсальность значительно затруднила бы **смысловое различение фонем**, обозначаемых буквами  И, Е, Я, У, поэтому на практике мы этого не видим.

Тогда причина **не в особой фонетике** звука звук [у]  – просто такая ситуация сложилась  **исторически**,  в процессе развития языка.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ (редукция звука У, первая степень редукции)

1. **РЕДУКЦИЯ ПО ТВЕРДОМУ ВАРИАНТУ**: гудеть.

Возможные фонетические формы – Ы , А,  но ближе  форма Ы.
Звук Ы обычно используется после твердых шипящих: ж(ы)лезо, ж(ы) леть.  У этого звука вообще  ограниченная сочетаемость – так, после твердых заднеязычных Г, К, Х он практически не употребляется. Нет, не подходит он для  редуцированного варианта звука У, лучше  уж оставить собственное лабиализованное произношение (даже если оно более затратное).

**Примечание.** Что касается лабиализованной фонемы О, то ее представляет безударный звук А. Различительная способность получается неполной, но с учетом контекста вполне допустимой

2. **РЕДУКЦИЯ ПО МЯГКОМУ ВАРИАНТУ:**  ключи.

Основная форма редуцированных звуков – это И (летать, сидеть,  рябина),  три фонемы реализуются в И.  Здесь действительно будут проблемы со смыслоразличением. Опять же оставляем собственное лабиализованное произношение.

Comment: Проголосовал за ваш ответ. Мне трудно оценить, насколько он верный, но я считаю, что вы мыслите в правильном направлении. Тут действительно дело, скорей всего, в балансе между удобством произношения (как вы сказали «энергозатратностью») и смысловым различением фонем.

Comment: Спасибо за голос. Тема редукции вообще очень интересна.  Позже я включу дополнительный материал в свой ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Вас, должно быть, устроил бы ответ, который содержал бы указание на особенности /i/ и /u/, препятствующие их качественной редукции. Но, вообще говоря, таких особенностей (связанных с физиологической стороной производства этих звуков или с их акустическим представлением) нет. Принято считать, что подобные факты – это отображение того, как устроена конкретная языковая система. Почему она так устроена? Потому что так сложилось. Почему так сложилось? «Потому что». (Хотя, конечно, исследования в этом направлении есть, но точных ответов они дать не призваны и едва ли могут.)

/i/, /ɨ/, /u/ объединяет то, что это закрытые гласные, занимающие верхнюю параллель [вокалической трапецоиды](https://www.google.com/search?q=vowel%20space&newwindow=1&sxsrf=ALeKk036pMTcfb_c0rBQdzfS_RMRHs-JLQ:1629805120637&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=6bsJvOjrCYAAbM%252CIlaY-wVOcnHMkM%252C_&vet=1&usg=AI4_-kRGUbu8Sckzi9jCywPC7GSRwHhcdA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj4vpKaycnyAhUiSfEDHcn7AL4Q_h16BAgiEAE#imgrc=6bsJvOjrCYAAbM). Вот что, а не лабиализация могло бы, по вашей логике, ответить на вопрос «почему». Но, безусловно, это всего лишь генерализация, но никакое не объяснение.

От абстрактных рассуждений – к конкретным примерам.

Во-первых, вы не правы, что эти фонемы не редуцируются. В разговорной речи это происходит довольно часто, что неоднократно отмечалось (ср., например, учебник Князева и Пожарицкой, Большой орфоэпический словарь Касаткиных и Каленчук). В слове *акк**у**ммулятор* выделенная гласная, например, должна произноситься как шва (или как [ъ], иначе говоря), вариант с [u] – допустимый (см. в БОС, упомянутый выше). В старшей норме окончания -ий часто произносились со швой (с [ъ]). В слове *дымоход* /ɨ/ нормально реализуется швой [ъ].

Во-вторых, в языках мира редукция /i/, /u/ и т. п. до швы встречается (ср. язык тауйа, монтанье, томпсон...).

Comment: Второй ответ ближе к тому, что меня интересует, в отличие от первого. Я знаю про трапецоиду (и про закрытость и напряжённость), но это всё равно не отвечает на вопрос о причинах отсутствия качественной редукции. Практика показывает, что практически у всего «так сложилось» в филологии есть какая-то причина. Ведь эти звуки могли «завести» себе «свой» редуцированный, но в фонетике этого не произошло.